# Trouble with File Server storing user profile data

Tags: windows-server-2012

I am having trouble with a newly added file server which does not seem to be storing roaming user profile data.

I have built the network with a domain controller and I have recently added a File Server, and built several client machines. Trouble is after having created the network I cannot get the File Server to see the roaming profile data, when I log into the client machines they don't display the mapped H drive in the My Computer window, nor does the File Server appear to be storing any of the user profile data.

The funny thing is before we got the file server, when I created the roaming profile system on the domain controller it all worked beautifully showing the mapped H drive on the client machines and the stored user folders/files on the domain controller. But now that I have added the file server (and rebuilt everything from scratch) it does not work.

Here is a breakdown of how I have built the network:

Domain Controller:
OS: Windows Server 2012
Name: DC01
AD installed with domain name as StewNet.org, user name added to OU with profile set to H: and then \FP01\PROFILES\%username%
DHCP installed with ip scope configured
DNS installed
IP: 192.168.1.50
Subnet: 255.255.255.0
Default Gateway: 192.168.1.1
Preferred DNS: 127.0.0.1

File Server:
OS: Windows Server 2012
As this machine is a server and has a static ip address, the name of the File Server (FP01) was manually added into the computers folder on AD machine so it would not fall under the dynamic ip assignments of the client computers (which I have set to join a different OU)
Name: FP01 (has been joined to StewNet domain)
PROFILES folder created on C drive set to shared with Authenticated Users and read/write permissions
IP: 192.168.1.70
Subnet: 255.255.255.0
Default Gateway: 192.168.1.1
Preferred DNS: 192.168.1.50 -> (this was the only way I could get the File Server to join StewNet domain)

Windows Client Machines:
OS: Windows 7 Pro x64 as well as some Windows 8.1 machines (have been joined to domain)
IP: Dynamically assigned via DHCP

Any ideas??

Comment: Is `\FP01\PROFILES\%username%` just a tip error?? Because it has to be `\\FP01`. If you are on your client, can you access manually `\\FP01\...`?

Comment: Hi, first of all yes was just a type error in this forum, secondly i cannot access the \\FP01\PROFILES\ via explorer..

Comment: It sounds like a DNS error. Try `nslookup FP01`. If you dont get an answer, look at your DNS config, if FP01 has an A Record Entry.

Comment: Have you configured roaming profiles for the users and configured the file server as the location of those roaming profiles? If not then you shouldn't expect to see user profiles on the file server.

Comment: Does your DHCP scope cover the IP address of FP01 ? Is te IP address reserved for FP01 on your DHCP ?

Comment: To answer maddin - nslookup from the client returns ok for the DC01 (domain controller) but returns no result for the FP01 (file server), also both servers will ping but the FP01 server replies with the IPv6 instead of IPv4. Also in the FP01 event logs there are a number of DNS warnings such as 8015 & 8019.

Comment: To answer joeqwert - yes when the user profiles created in AD then on the profiles tab H: is selected and the path is set to \\FP01\PROFILES\%username% and yes also the PROFILES folder is shared.

Comment: To answer NooJ - The FP server is statically assigned not dynamically so does not fall into thew DHCP scope, the DHCP scope which is 192.168.1.100 - 254, whereas the FP server has a static IP of 192.168.1.70 and has been manually added to the DC01 server.

Comment: Its all ok - I found out what I was doing wrong, I was logging into the FP01 server with the built in "Administrator" account, so not logging directly onto the domain, I have created another "support" account with domain admins privileges and then logged in with this, and now everything working fine, thanks for all your efforts all the same :).